# Definir um comentário padrão para todo novo projeto

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, comentários

Preciso definir um comentário padrão, para que em todo projeto que for criado ele apareça, sem que seja necessário digitá-lo toda vez.

*Ex.: \Author: Pedro H.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os gabaritos usados para iniciar os códigos ficam em `C:\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\1033\` e pode mexer neles à vontade.

Obviamente que `VisualStudioInstallationDirectory` é onde está o seu VS, geralmente em `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`.

Porém, isso é uma coisa que se usava muito nos anos 70/80. Com o [controle de versão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_controle_de_vers%C3%B5es) as pessoas pararam de fazer isso. Se duas pessoas mexerem no código, quem é o autor? Colocar esse tipo de comentário hoje é considerado um erro. Não vai causar grande mal, mas se quer fazer bem feito, não coloque coisas que não devem estar em código.